# How can I partition using a BINARY column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have so far only found the following very unelegant solution to creating a `TABLE` with a `PARTITION` on a `BINARY` column in MySQL (not part of primary key, so I can't use `PARTITION BY KEY`):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestPartition (
  uuid BINARY(16) NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(uuid) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (X'10000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (X'20000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (X'30000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (X'40000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (X'50000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (X'60000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (X'70000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (X'80000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (X'90000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (X'A0000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION pA VALUES LESS THAN (X'B0000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION pB VALUES LESS THAN (X'C0000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION pC VALUES LESS THAN (X'D0000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION pD VALUES LESS THAN (X'E0000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION pE VALUES LESS THAN (X'F0000000000000000000000000000000'),
    PARTITION pF VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

Is there a better way to do this? This becomes unpleasant if I want more partitions.

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: Could you refine your question? What aspect of the set-up do you have questions about?

Comment: This kind of partitioning is very unlikely to provide any performance benefit.  UUID indexing is bad, especially for huge tables; this does not help any.

Comment: @RickJames Can you expand, possibly make that an answer? I do not know why UUID indexing is bad or why this partition would not help.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY(uuid)` (without partitioning) would work a lot better for all operations involving `WHERE uuid="..."`.  Two articles by me:  [_uuids_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) and [_partitioning_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).